# VETTED_PARTNER Status for Google Business Profile API

Tags: google-api

I am trying to use the Google Business Profile API to verify locations, etc.  using the VETTED_PARTNER method, but I am unable to do so because I am not a `"Vetted Partner."`

I couldn't find any details on how to become a `Vetted Partner` or at what level this status is needed.

Could someone help with the following questions:

How can I become a `Vetted Partner`?
Is it needed for every client?

I tried used the API to list my accounts and it shows that I'm not vetted for any of them, but I do have owner access.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge*, The *Vetted Partner* program by Google is intended to be used by enterprises, in particular 3rd party agencies.

In addition, Google has announced to its partners that the program will be discontinued beginning May 31, 2023.

It is yet mentioned in the API docs as you have stated but, due to this, I think it is better to evaluate other solutions to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

*: I work for Italiaonline, an enterprise that is qualified as a vetted partner

Comment: any chance they provided more information about it being "discontinued". Will they provide an alternative solution or is it simply "just use the other verification options".

Comment: @JamesGilchrist: as you said, as of today, I can confirm the _Vetted Partner_ program will be discontinued as planned. If you are lucky the location will be verified automatically by the AI using Google Maps photos, otherwise you have to leverage the methods proposed by Google itself. It could be a simple giveback of the code sent by SMS till a planned video call to confirm the existence of the activity (i.e., this is required for banks and other important institutions)